# Importing existing AWS Resources using Terraform Module

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to import the existing S3 bucket using terraform module.I am able to import it successfully but the issue I am facing now is that after successful import when I ran terraform plan command it still showing that its going to create the resource again. It would be great if some one could help me what I am doing wrong here.

**My Module:**

```
module "log_s3" {
  source               = "../modules/s3/"
  env_name             = var.env_name
  bucket_name          = "${var.product_name}-logs-${var.env_name}"
  enable_versioning    = false
  enable_cors          = false
  logging_bucket       = module.log_s3.log_bucket_id
  enable_bucket_policy = true
  enable_static_site   = false
}
```

**My resource:**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_protected_bucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
  tags = {
    environment              = var.env_name
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "my_protected_bucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id
  acl    = var.enable_static_site == true ? "public-read" : "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "my_protected_bucket_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id

  # Block public access
  block_public_acls       = var.enable_static_site == true ? false : true
  block_public_policy     = var.enable_static_site == true ? false : true
  ignore_public_acls      = var.enable_static_site == true ? false : true
  restrict_public_buckets = var.enable_static_site == true ? false : true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "my_protected_bucket_versioning" {
  count  = var.enable_versioning ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration" "my_protected_bucket_cors" {
  count  = var.enable_cors ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
    expose_headers  = [""]
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      cors_rule
    ]
  }

}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "my_protected_bucket_ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "ObjectWriter"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "my_protected_bucket_sse_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      sse_algorithm = "AES256"
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "my_protected_bucket_policy" {
  count  = var.enable_bucket_policy ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-1659086042176",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1659086041783",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.arn}/*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "my_protected_bucket_object" {
  bucket = var.logging_bucket
  key    = "s3_log/${aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id}/"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "my_protected_bucket_logging" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id
  target_bucket = var.logging_bucket
  target_prefix = "s3_log/${aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id}/"
  depends_on    = [aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket, aws_s3_object.my_protected_bucket_object]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "my_protected_bucket_static" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id
  count  = var.enable_static_site ? 1 : 0

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "error.html"
  }
}
```

**output.tf**

```
output "log_bucket_id" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket.id
```

**Terraform Import command:**
I ran the below command to import the bucket

```
terraform import module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket abcd-logs-dev
```

**output :**

```
module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_s3_bucket for import
module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket: Refreshing state... [id=abcd-logs-deveu]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

**Terraform plan:**

After successfull import ..when I ran **terraform plan** command its showing that terraform going to create new resources

```
module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket: Refreshing state... [id=abcd-logs-dev]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_acl.my_protected_bucket_acl will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "my_protected_bucket_acl" {
      + acl    = "private"
      + bucket = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + access_control_policy {
          + grant {
              + permission = (known after apply)

              + grantee {
                  + display_name  = (known after apply)
                  + email_address = (known after apply)
                  + id            = (known after apply)
                  + type          = (known after apply)
                  + uri           = (known after apply)
                }
            }

          + owner {
              + display_name = (known after apply)
              + id           = (known after apply)
            }
        }
    }

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_logging.my_protected_bucket_logging will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "my_protected_bucket_logging" {
      + bucket        = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + id            = (known after apply)
      + target_bucket = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + target_prefix = "s3_log/abcd-logs-dev/"
    }

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.my_protected_bucket_ownership will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "my_protected_bucket_ownership" {
      + bucket = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + rule {
          + object_ownership = "ObjectWriter"
        }
    }

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_policy.my_protected_bucket_policy[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "my_protected_bucket_policy" {
      + bucket = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + policy = jsonencode(
            {
              + Id        = "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-145342356879"
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = "s3:PutObject"
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Principal = {
                          + Service = "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
                        }
                      + Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::abcd-logs-dev/*"
                      + Sid       = "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-145342356879"
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
    }

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.my_protected_bucket_access will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "my_protected_bucket_access" {
      + block_public_acls       = true
      + block_public_policy     = true
      + bucket                  = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + id                      = (known after apply)
      + ignore_public_acls      = true
      + restrict_public_buckets = true
    }

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration.my_protected_bucket_sse_config will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "my_protected_bucket_sse_config" {
      + bucket = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + rule {
          + apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
              + sse_algorithm = "AES256"
            }
        }
    }

  # module.log_s3.aws_s3_object.my_protected_bucket_object will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_object" "my_protected_bucket_object" {
      + acl                    = "private"
      + bucket                 = "abcd-logs-dev"
      + bucket_key_enabled     = (known after apply)
      + content_type           = (known after apply)
      + etag                   = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy          = false
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + key                    = "s3_log/abcd-logs-dev/"
      + kms_key_id             = (known after apply)
      + server_side_encryption = (known after apply)
      + storage_class          = (known after apply)
      + tags_all               = (known after apply)
      + version_id             = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 7 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

It would be great if some one could help out what I am doing wrong. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the simple problem here is that you are only importing S3 bucket resource into your state.

When you use a module, it's not enough to just import a single resource within that module. You have to run import command for all the resources present in that module.

You are currently running below import command.

```
terraform import module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket.my_protected_bucket abcd-logs-dev
```

This is importing only S3 bucket into your state. But if you look at your module, you have other resources as well. So, you have to run similar import commands for other resources as well which are present in your module like below.

```
terraform import module.log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_acl.my_protected_bucket_acl abcd-logs-dev
```

Please check below for s3 bucket acl import https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_acl#import

Similarly, run the import command for all the resources in your module and then run `terraform plan`. It will work.

Comment: thankyou for the guidence..but it seems i cant use the same module to import the other resources..

```Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on /home/laptop-obs-138/biologit/test/pv-deploy/deploy/terraform/mlmai/main.tf line 4, in module "log_s3":
│    4:   bucket_name          = "${var.product_name}-logs-${var.env_name}"
│ 
│ An argument named "bucket_name" is not expected here.```

Comment: Importing via modules requires that your configuration is matching exactly to the actual resource created in the cloud like AWS here.

Answer (score 0):

The resource you imported is of type `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket` and named `my_protected_bucket`. There is no resource of type `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket` listed in the Terraform plan output. It correctly imported the S3 bucket resource and is not trying to create a new S3 bucket.

The resource types the Terraform plan say it is going to create are:

- `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_acl`
- `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_logging`
- `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls`
- `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_policy`
- `log_s3.aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block`
- `log_s3.aws_s3_object`

You haven't imported any of those resources yet. You still need to import each of those resources.

Comment: Ahh..perfectly make sense ..Thanks a lot for pulling out..